# Strange EJB behavior or am I missing something???

Tags: java, ejb, javabeans, java-ee-6

Here is a very strange behavior using EJB beans:

```
@Local
public interface Provider {
    void test();
}

@Local
public interface ExtProvider extends Provider {
   void test2();
}

public abstract class AbstractProvider implements Provider {
   @Override 
   void test(){ System.out.println("Hello strange " + getTech()); }
   protected abstract String getTech();          
}

public abstract class ExtAbstractProvider extends AbstractProvider implements ExtProvider {
   @Override
   void test2() { System.out.println("Hello from " + getName());}
   @Override
   String getTech() { return "extended EJB";}
   protected abstract String getName();
}
@Stateless
public class ProviderBean extends AbstractProvider {
   @Override
   protected String getTech() { return "EJB";}
}

@Stateless
public class ExtProviderBean extends ExtAbstractProvider {
  @Override
  protected String getName() { return "ext provider";}
}
```

According to the above code, if I write:

```
@EJB Provider provider; // should inject an instance of ProviderBean
@EJB ExtProvider extProvider; // should inject an instance of ExtProviderBean
```

but no one of the two works!!! Someone would say that in this example the EJB doesn't know which instance to create each time since there are two instances that implements Provider. And the strange is: it works only if we declare the two beans as:

```
public class ExtProviderBean extends ExtAbstractProvider implements ExtProvider
public class ProviderBean extends AbstractProvider implements Provider
```

In this case the code works. The problem is that we have to explicitly define that an implementation bean implements the interface even it is implicitly defined from the abstract implementation. Am I missing something or this is a limitation?

Comment: I'm not sure about EJB 3.1 but I guess the container will create the implicit local interface only for the actual EJB class or use directly implemented interfaces - especially since `AbstractProvider` isn't annotated at all (at the class level) and thus might ne be recognized as being an EJB.

Comment: I have two questions: Can I annotate an abstract class? Shouldn't EJB container know that the Provider interface has ProviderBean as implementation, after all this is implicitly defined by extending AbstractProvider so when some other bean do: @EJB Provider prv; would inject an instance of ProviderBean. Of course there is a problem here: the container can inject an instance of ExtProviderBean since this is a Provider to. But is there any other way to solve this without declaring the class to explicitly implement its local interface (it's a bit weird from my perspective)?

Comment: As I said I'm no JEE 6 expert but in JEE 5 (and thus EJB 3.0) dependency injection would reject multiple implementations for the same EJB interface (at least that's my experience). You might do that with providing more information (e.g. using the `beanName` attribute) but I'd favor using explicit interfaces. Btw, `it doesn't work` is quite vague, can you give more information?

Comment: Well, it doesn't inject the bean (Provider).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read through [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052463/ejb-3-1-is-local-annotation-needed) and I think the provided answer also applies to your case.

I am just citing a part of the answer and thereby the EE spec:

```
@Stateless
public class A implements Foo { ... }

@Stateless
public class B extends A implements Bar { ... }
```

> Assuming Foo and Bar are local business interfaces and there is no
>   associated deployment descriptor, **session bean A exposes local
>   business interface Foo and session bean B exposes local business
>   interface Bar, but not Foo.** Session bean B would need to explicitly
>   include Foo in its set of exposed views for that interface to apply.