# EJB 3.1. Is @Local annotation needed?

Tags: glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

So far, I almost always worked with no-interface EJBs and have a slight understanding about the need of @Local annotation. Consider this example:

```
public interface MyBeanIntf { void doStuff(); }

@Stateless
public class MyBean implements MyBeanIntf { public void doStuff(){ } }
```

Should the `MyBeanIntf` be marked as `@Local`? I don't see any benefit from that, because even when I don't annotate it as `@Local`, I still can use **DI** to properly inject it into UI Controller:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TestController implements Serializable {

  // injection works perfectly, even when MyBeanIntf is not marked as @Local
  @Inject
  private MyBeanIntf myBean;

  // or even like this:
  // @EJB
  // private MyBeanIntf myBean;

}
```

Let's make it more complex:

```
public interface MyBeanIntf { void doStuff(); }
public class MySuperBean implements MyBeanIntf { public void doStuff() { } }

@Stateless
public class MyBean extends MySuperBean { }
```

Is `MyBean` now considered a valid `Local EJB` bean? I have some doubts because it implements the interface indirectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your EJB implements some interface but you don't specify (neither on the EJB nor the interface itself) which interface it is (@Remote, @Local) than it's assumed that it's a @Local one.

Therefore your code:

```
public interface MyBeanIntf { void doStuff(); }

@Stateless
public class MyBean implements MyBeanIntf { public void doStuff(){ } }
```

is semantically identical to the following:

```
@Local
public interface MyBeanIntf { void doStuff(); }

@Stateless
public class MyBean implements MyBeanIntf { public void doStuff(){ } }
```

When it comes to the second part of your question, I think that section **4.9.2.1 Session Bean Superclasses** from EJB 3.1 FR spec would be interesting for you. From my understanding (so it might not be correct), it seems that your bean should not be considered as exposing a valid Local interface because of the following excerpt:

```
@Stateless
public class A implements Foo { ... }

@Stateless
public class B extends A implements Bar { ... }
```

> Assuming Foo and Bar are local business interfaces and there is no
>   associated deployment descriptor, session bean A exposes local
>   business interface Foo and **session bean B exposes local business
>   interface Bar, but not Foo**.
>
> Session bean B would need to explicitly include Foo in its set of
>   exposed views for that interface to apply.

**Update:**

As an addition one more excerpt from the spec:

> A session bean class is permitted to have superclasses that are
>   themselves session bean classes. However, there are no special rules
>   that apply to the processing of annotations or the deployment
>   descriptor for this case. For the purposes of processing a particular
>   session bean class, **all superclass processing is identical regardless
>   of whether the superclasses are themselves session bean classes.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As for the link to the specification, I still have some doubts. It explicitly discusses the superclasses, that are session beans themselves. But what if they are just abstract classes without `@Stateless` or `@Stateful` annotation?

Comment: Sure, I'm not sure about that in 100%, but take a look at the edited post - maybe it'll help.

Comment: Thanks for the emphasis. I read that part in the spec myself, but somehow missed it.